# Can anyone recongize the font from showoff.io

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I like the font (or style of font) used for the logo of the site:
https://showoff.io/.

[image: Showoff Logo]

Is there a place to find such fonts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably its **lucida fax.**
its from lucida family.and inner shadow has been applied to give such look.

**you can get such fonts from these sites...**

1. 1001freefonts
2. Urbanfonts
3. Betterfonts
4. Searchfreefonts
5. Dafont

Comment: While there are a few decent typefaces to be found on those sites, for the most part, they are landfills of crappy typography. FYI, Lucida is a commercial face, so you're not going to find original versions on the free sites. MyFonts would be the place to go: http://new.myfonts.com/search/Lucida/fonts/

Comment: It isn't Lucida Fax, although it's quite similar. Check the 'f'.

Comment: ... and the dots on the i and period, and the serifs on the h and s - actually, it's got quite a lot of differences.

Answer (score 7):

The font used for the logo is actually Stag (in Medium weight): http://www.christianschwartz.com/stag.shtml

Comment: Very well spotted.

Comment: exactly it is..